# Convert an array of objects into a nested array of objects with different keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

So i have an array with the below structure. how would i go about converting it to the nested array below.

```
[
   {mainCategory: 'Brand', slug: 'brand', value: 'Brand', label: 'Brand'},
   {category: 'Cat1', slug: 'cat1', value: 'Cat1', label: 'Cat1'},
   {subCategory: 'SubCat1', slug: 'subcat1', value: 'SubCat1', label: 'SubCat1'},
   {mainCategory: 'Type', slug: 'type', value: 'Type', label: 'Type'},
   {category: 'Cat2', slug: 'cat2', value: 'Cat2', label: 'Cat2'},
   {subCategory: 'SubCat2', slug: 'subcat2', value: 'Cat2', label: 'Cat2'},
]
```

```
[
   {label: 'Brand', options:
       [
         { label: Cat1, value: Cat1 }, 
         { label: SubCat1, value: SubCat1 } 
       ]
   },
   {label: 'Type', options:
       [
         { label: Cat2, value: Cat2 }, 
         { label: SubCat2, value: SubCat2 } 
       ]
   },
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please may you share that attempt?

Comment: That seems like a dicey data structure. You're relying on it being in an exact order so you can organize data rather than having some kind of explicit parent/child relationship. That said, how do you think you'd go about it?

Comment: no idea at the moment. been up all night and its bothered me that i couldn't get it done haha. However i just decided to map the query result differently and it's working atm. but i still question how this could be done haha

Comment: You need to have some conditions for it to do dynamic. For example u need to any key that tells u which one is belong to which one.

Comment: Is the last element of the input data supposed to have `SubCat2` in its `value` and `label`, to match the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the array elements. If it's a `mainCategory` object, create a new array element for the result. Otherwise, push the nested object onto the current result element's `options` array.

```js
const input_data = [
   {mainCategory: 'Brand', slug: 'brand', value: 'Brand', label: 'Brand'},
   {category: 'Cat1', slug: 'cat1', value: 'Cat1', label: 'Cat1'},
   {subCategory: 'SubCat1', slug: 'subcat1', value: 'SubCat1', label: 'SubCat1'},
   {mainCategory: 'Type', slug: 'type', value: 'Type', label: 'Type'},
   {category: 'Cat2', slug: 'cat2', value: 'Cat2', label: 'Cat2'},
   {subCategory: 'SubCat2', slug: 'subcat2', value: 'Cat2', label: 'Cat2'},
];

const result = [];
let current;
input_data.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.mainCategory) {
    current = {
      label: obj.mainCategory,
      options: []
    };
    result.push(current);
  } else {
    current.options.push({
      label: obj.label,
      value: obj.value
    });
  }
});

console.log(result);
```